# Node.js + MongoDB does not commit upsert, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can not see changes sent to web server, why?

- server is running
- I can see in console before `save` the correct JSON: `{ "_id" : "abcd", "key1" : "value1" }`

This is the body of my POST message:

```
["Memorise", [["Diagram", {"_id" : "ab3sdscd", "key2" : "value1"}]]]
```

---

```
var http = require('http');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var myServer = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
    if (request.method == 'POST') {

    var data = '';

    request.on('data', function (chunk){
        data += chunk;
    });

    request.on('end',function(){

        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        var databaseName = obj['db']

        MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/" + databaseName, function(err, db) {

            if(!err) {

                if (obj.length == 2) {

                    var recordsToUpsert = obj[1]
                    for (var i = 0; i < recordsToUpsert.length; i++) {

                        var recordToUpsertAndCollection = recordsToUpsert[i]
                        var collectionName = recordToUpsertAndCollection[0];
                        var recordToUpsert = recordToUpsertAndCollection[1];
                        var collection = db.collection(collectionName);

                        //console.log(collection)
                        console.log(recordToUpsert)
                        collection.save(recordToUpsert, {w:1}, {

                            //console.log("record upserted");
                        });
                    };

                    response.writeHead(200)
                    response.end()
                }
            }
        });
    });
    }   
});
myServer.listen(3000)
```

Comment: Are you saying that the body of the request is what is being parsed into `obj`? Where is the 'db' key? I just see an array with two elements. Also you should not be connecting to MongoDB or any database "per request". If anything, pool the connection  and just select the "database namespace" for the request, which is quite easy to do.

Comment: correct, first element is the `databaseName` called `Memorise`, `collectionName` called `Diagram`

Comment: But you are asking for `obj['db']` and that does not exist `obj[0]` would be the first element of the array. JavaScript "stringifies" just about everywhere. So it looks like you are connecting to the "undefined" database. Your upserts are there.

Comment: Re-read what I added just then. That tells you the database name your data has been inserted into.

Answer (score 1):

This is your payload being parsed into `obj`:

```
["Memorise", [["Diagram", {"_id" : "ab3sdscd", "key2" : "value1"}]]]
```

Here's the problem:

```
 var databaseName = obj['db']
```

See that you are asking for the "key" named "db". It does not exist so databaseName is `undefined`.

Since JavaScript "stringifies", then the connection string comes out like this:

```
"mongodb://localhost:27017/undefined"
```

That is where all your data is going to.

Fix it by this simple change:

```
 var databaseName = obj[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

> collection.update(criteria, update[[, options], callback]);

for upsert rather save ?

Try this:

> collection.update({_id: recordToUpsert._id}, recordToUpsert, {upsert:true}, yourCallbackMethod);

See this link:
[upsert](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html)

Comment: `.save()` is basically a wrapper for "upsert". Always has been. That isn't the problem. It's a coding logic error.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that :)